# Confused about Bootstrap Non-responsive grid system

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, haml

I'm trying to build a **non-responsive** form in bootstrap.

I've followed the instructions on the bootstrap site [here](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/non-responsive/)

But instead of getting something like this,

[image: RESULT]

I'm getting this instead.

[image: problem]

Can someone explain what's going wrong? My understanding is that I can create each component and that they automatically line-up inline? But they're stacking instead?

My code is below: I've used haml.

Haml:

```
%body
 .container
  .form
   .row
    .col-xs-8.col-xs-offset-2
      %h3 This is a header
      .form-group
        %label.control-label.col-xs-4 Label
        %input.state.col-xs-4.form-control/
        .dropdown.col-xs-4
          .btn.btn-default.dropdown-toggle{"data-toggle" => "dropdown"}
            Button
            %span.caret
      .form-group
        %label.col-xs-4.control-label Another Label
        .col-xs-4
          %input.state.form-control/
        .dropdown.col-xs-2
          .btn.btn-default.dropdown-toggle{"data-toggle" => "dropdown"}
            Another button
            %span.caret
```

Css:

```
.container {
  width: 1440px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  max-width: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

anything within the same line should get a `.pull-left` class.
before the second line you should clear floats

```
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```